# Subsetting by Unique Values of a Variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I am trying to build a model where all I need is two vectors, on of binomial event outcomes and the other variable is time associated with the outcome. I need to drop repeated times so I use unique(time). The problem is that then the event outcomes are not aligned with the unique times. I have tried subsetting event outcome with outcomes[unique(time)] but that does not work. How would I subset the events with the unique times?

SHOT  |  CUMULATIVE TIME

"made" 1:12

"miss" 2:32

"made" 2:32

"miss" 2:34

Here is an example table of my data, I would want to remove the third row in this instance.

Comment: You can try `outcomes[!duplicated(time)]`

Comment: It would be far better to have a reproducible question with sample data and expected output. Some questions can be addressed hypothetically, but there are too often un-spoken assumptions that slow the process down. As has been suggested to you before, please provide sample data by posting the output of `dput(x)` where `x` is enough rows of your data to demonstrate the duplication issue, but not too big that it floods the screen with gobs of unnecessary data. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to provide a barebones example. And thank you Brian that does work. One more question: how do I change the time of the third shot by just four or five seconds from using a loop to ensure that the time will not coincide with or be greater than the  cumulative time of the fourth shot? Apologies in advance for that wording...

Comment: Clearly rows 2 and 3 have duplicated times. Why do you want to keep row 2 and not row 3?  Do you always keep the first to occur? Always keep the "miss" if there is a "made" and a "miss"? Something else?

Comment: As to "changing the time of the third shot by just four or five seconds" - what is the class of that column? Is it `character` or are you using a time class? (We wouldn't have to ask if you shared your example with `dput()` so it's reproducible...) Do you want to add 5 seconds always? Randomly add 4 or 5 seconds? And why do you want to change it--I thought you wanted to remove it? Changing and removing are pretty different. Instead of asking new questions in comments, I'd recommend either asking a new question with a clear explanation or at least editing your question to provide details.